# Next.js React Component Executing on Server Side Instead of Client Side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

I am facing an issue with a React component in my Next.js application. The component is meant for a mobile navigation menu and uses certain hooks and modules. However, it seems to be executing on the server side instead of the client side. Here is the relevant code:

```
'use client'

import { ArrowRight, Menu } from 'lucide-react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const MobileNav = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const toggleOpen = () => setOpen((prev) => {
    console.log("toggling menu");
    return !prev
  })

  const pathname = usePathname()
  console.log(pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("calling use effect");
    if (isOpen) toggleOpen()
  }, [isOpen, pathname])

  const closeOnCurrent = (href: string) => {
    if (pathname === href) {
      console.log("closing the menu");
      toggleOpen()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='sm:hidden'>
      <Menu
        onClick={toggleOpen}
        className='relative z-50 h-5 w-5 text-zinc-700'
      />

      {isOpen ? (
        <div className='fixed animate-in slide-in-from-top-5 fade-in-20 inset-0 z-0 w-full'>
          <ul className='absolute bg-white border-b border-zinc-200 shadow-xl grid w-full gap-3 px-10 pt-20 pb-8'>
            <li>
              <Link
                onClick={() =>
                  closeOnCurrent('/contact')
                }
                className='flex items-center w-full font-semibold'
                href='/contact'>
                Contact Us
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MobileNav
```

**Issue:**
The problem is that when I run my application, the `useEffect` and `usePathname` hooks don't seem to behave as expected, and the component appears to be running on the server side.

`console.log(pathname)` inside the component logs the correct path in the server

[image]

Why might this code be executing on the server side despite the intention for client-side execution?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

„use client“ components run partly on the server, render what they can render and hydrate at the client with the rest. Here you can find a good explanation: https://nextjs-faq.com/browser-api-client-component